# Javascript easy math exercise

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<input onclick="result.value = m1*m2; m1.value = (+m1.value -1);" type="button" id="minus1" value="minus" />
<input onclick="result.value = m1*m2; m1.value = (+m1.value +1);" type="button" id="plus1" value="plus" />
<input type="textbox" id="m1" value="1" />
<br />
<input onclick="result.value = m1*m2; m2.value = (+m2.value -1);" type="button" id="minus2" value="minus" />
<input onclick="result.value = m1*m2; m2.value = (+m2.value +1);" type="button" id="plus2" value="plus" />
<input type="textbox" id="m2" value="1" />
<br />
<br />
Result :<input type="textbox" id="result" />
</body>
</html>
```

Why am I getting NaN value every time I change any of the + or - buttons???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are multiplying `m1*m2`. You should use: `m1.value*m2.value`.

In some browsers, `m1` would return the element with id `m1` itself. What you want to multiply, though, is just the value, thus `m1.value`.

Edited HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input onclick="result.value = m1.value*m2.value; m1.value = (+m1.value -1);" type="button" id="minus1" value="minus" />
        <input onclick="result.value = m1.value*m2.value; m1.value = (+m1.value +1);" type="button" id="plus1" value="plus" />
        <input type="textbox" id="m1" value="1" />
        <br />
        <input onclick="result.value = m1.value*m2.value; m2.value = (+m2.value -1);" type="button" id="minus2" value="minus" />
        <input onclick="result.value = m1.value*m2.value; m2.value = (+m2.value +1);" type="button" id="plus2" value="plus" />
        <input type="textbox" id="m2" value="1" />
        <br />
        <br />Result :
        <input type="textbox" id="result" />
    </body>
</html>
```

If I may suggest, you should use a function in the `onclick` event. Things will be clearer, easier to maintain, and **you can add more checks**, like if the number on the input is valid. See an example below.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function update(inputToChange, changeValue) {
                var parsedValue = parseFloat(inputToChange.value);
                if (isNaN(parsedValue)) {
                   alert(inputToChange.value+' is not a a valid number.');
                }
                else {
                   result.value = m1.value * m2.value;
                   inputToChange.value = parsedValue + changeValue;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <input onclick="update(m1, -1)" type="button" id="minus1" value="minus" />
       <input onclick="update(m1, 1)" type="button" id="plus1" value="plus" />
       <input type="textbox" id="m1" value="1" />
       <br />
       <input onclick="update(m2, -1)" type="button" id="minus2" value="minus" />
       <input onclick="update(m2, 1)" type="button" id="plus2" value="plus" />
       <input type="textbox" id="m2" value="1" />
       <br />
       <br />Result :
       <input type="textbox" id="result" />
    </body>
</html>
```

[Check demo here](http://jsbin.com/upiqep/3/edit).

Comment: Ah so obvious mistake... Sorry for even opening a thread for this!! ++

Comment: Honest mistake, it happens! Since we are here, though, I added a suggestion (using a function). Check it out, it may be of help.

Comment: @fame additionally, it might be a goo idea to do a `parseFloat(m1.value)` in case the user provided erroneous input.

Comment: Haha I just found an another thread where they suggested the same! Thank you guys!

Comment: I added @Christoph suggestion. Check in the answer an example where the function validates if the `<input>` has a number before continuing.

Comment: Updated the answer (there was a minor typo in the validation function). Check it out!

Answer (score 1):

You have use `m1*m2` which is Id of textboxes not its values.

use: `result.value = m1.value*m2.value` insteed of `result.value = m1*m2;`